# Warning: 'class' does not contain '_PT_' with prefix and suffix

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've some warnings going on with the usual naming convention mess for operators.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing it properly, but Blender is not convinced yet...

This is the code:

```
class T4TOOLS_PT_t4_tagger_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "T4 Tagger v0.1.2"
    bl_idname = "t4tools.t4_tagger_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "T4Tools"
    bl_parent_id = "t4tools.main_panel"
 
    #qui si disegna roba
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene #capture scene context and keep it in memory
        tools = scene.t4_tagger_tool #reference pointer to properties, with better name 
        
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
        
        #adding properties to layout
        layout.prop(tools, "custom_tag")
        layout.prop(tools, "tag_enum")
        #adding button to layout
        layout.separator()
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("t4tools.t4_apply_tags_button")
```

Can't wrap my head around this, seems good to me but the system console says:

```
register_class(...):
Warning: 't4tools.t4_tagger_panel' does not contain '_PT_' with prefix and suffix
```

Besides of this, everything works fine, but this warning is really bothering me.
I've already checked other questions about this issue, but nothing is really helping to solve my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello ! `bl_idname` should match your class name exactly : `bl_idname = "T4TOOLS_PT_t4_tagger_panel"`

Comment: I've fixed this issue 5 minutes after asking.
The main problem is that _OT_ is the only one that is not following the naming convention... Operators can have bl_idname different from ***_OT_***.
That's what I was missing.
Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`__PT__` needs same id_name of class.
Only exception is `__OT__`, operators can have a different `bl_idname` from their class.

```
class T4TOOLS_PT_t4_tagger_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
        bl_label = "T4 Tagger v0.1.2"
        bl_idname = "T4TOOLS_PT_t4_tagger_panel"
        bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
        bl_region_type = 'UI'
        bl_category = "T4Tools"
        bl_parent_id = "t4tools.main_panel"
 
        def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene #capture scene context and keep it in memory
        tools = scene.t4_tagger_tool #reference pointer to properties, with better name 
        
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
        
        #adding properties to layout
        layout.prop(tools, "custom_tag")
        layout.prop(tools, "tag_enum")
        #adding button to layout
        layout.separator()
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("t4tools.t4_apply_tags_button")
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was getting similar warnings from a third-party addon I'm using, I started looking into this to find a fix I could send upstream.

The answer to this question got me searching for official documentation about it to cite as reference in the comments above my modifications to the addon's code but what I found is this:

[Blender API Docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html)

> Notice the ‘CATEGORY_PT_name’ Panel.bl_idname, this is a naming convention for panels.

and

> bl_idname
>
> If this is set, the panel gets a custom ID, otherwise it takes the name of the class used to define the panel. For example, if the class name is “OBJECT_PT_hello”, and bl_idname is not set by the script, then bl_idname = “OBJECT_PT_hello”

So basically:

- The class and `bl_idname` don't necessarily need to be same
- The `bl_idname` just need to have `_PT_` in its name as per the naming convention
- If `bl_idname` is omitted, it will inherit the class' name

Also good to note is that these are warnings and not errors, which explains why the OP code as well as the third party addon were working despite not following the naming convention.